# OS X "show desktop" [Control^] + [↓] shortcut does not work

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

**OS X "show desktop" [Control^] + [↓] shortcut does not work**, while any other shortcuts work fine including "mission control" [Control^] + [↑], switching desktops [Control^] + [←]or[→]

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.2. Here are my "Keyboard Shortcuts Settings":
 [image: <http://i.imgur.com/9sq8ksO.png>]

Note:
As I am former Win user I have Command and Control keys switched - so I am physically pressing Command key instead of Control, but nevertheless all shortcuts are working well except the "show desktop" one.

Anyone has any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved the problem myself. No idea why but **Mission Control shortcuts can be set in two different locations:**

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control
2. System Preferences > Mission Control > Keyboard and mouse shortcuts

In my case it was necessary to set shortcuts in both locations.

Answer (score -1):

This is totally annoying. I have the same problem after upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan. On version 10.11.3 right now. I am forced to use the Hot Corner feature to "Show Desktop"... for now until this is fixed (fingers crossed).

Comment: I didn't know about the Hot Corner feature, when I wanted to enable it i realized that Mission Control shortcuts can be also set there and in my case they were blank values "-". When I set them to appropriate keys, Show Desktop shortcut started to work fine! :D